# Laravel Eloquent Query for two tables

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have two tables and I want make one query with count.
My first table name is `orders` with fields :

| product_id | quantity |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |

My second table is `items` as bellow fields :

| id | product_id | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2.99 |
| 2 | 2 | 3.99 |
| 3 | 1 | 1.99 |
| 4 | 1 | 5.99 |

As you can see product ID:1 have more orders but in items table product ID 1 have 3 prices, I want to get product_id with more order also lowest price.

my query as bellow

```
Items::->withCount(['orders' => function($q){
            $q->active();
        }])
        ->orderBy('orders_count', 'desc')
        ->groupBy('product_id')
        ->limit(1)->get();
```

I am getting item with more orders but first record with price of 2.99 but I want to get 3rd record with price of 1.99 (its same product_id)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use another orderBy function to your query to get the lowest price.
Maybe the below code work!

```
Items::->withCount(['orders' => function($q){
            $q->active();
        }])
        ->orderBy('orders_count', 'desc')
        ->orderBy('price' , 'asc')
        ->groupBy('product_id')
        ->limit(1)->get();
```

Note: this syntax, work for laravel version 7 or higher

Comment: Sorry but its not working... my app is in larval 5.7

Answer (score 0):

I guess a simple raw select would return the expected result

```
Items::withCount(['orders' => function($q){
            $q->active();
        }])
        ->select(['product_id', DB::raw('min(price) as lowest_price')])
        ->orderBy('orders_count', 'desc')
        ->groupBy('product_id')
        ->limit(1)
        ->get();
```